# Get website's root directory using ftp details

Tags: php

In php is it possible to get a website's root directory using ftp details?
Using [`ftp_nlist()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) function it displays all directories.I want only the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

No. The FTP server doesn't know that - the web root directory is something that only the web server knows, and the FTP server isn't in communication with that.

Comment: @user2967705 And root directory is part of web server settings, not FTP server settings. Ftp will give you access to only what it was told, without knowing which one is the root directory for your host.

Comment: There is any way to know the root directory?